# how to use form_tag in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Hey all, I'm running into an error using form_tag in Rails 2.3 and can't seem to wrap my head around it. What may I be doing wrong syntactically?

```
      =form_tag :action => 'form', :name => "admin_form" 
        #images_actions_bar
          =submit_tag "Approve", :class => "button", :name => "approve"
          =submit_tag "Update", :class => "button", :name => "update"
```

I am seeing "syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end"

Comment: can you post your controller code as well?  the immediate error you are getting seems unrelated to the form cdoe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using the `=` output when you're using Rails 2. This is the new helper in Rails *3*. You want to use `-` for the `form_tag` in Rails 2.

EDIT: OP pointed out in the comments that he was missing a `do` at the end of the `form_tag` as well.

Comment: Okay you were right... turns out I also needed a "do" at the end... ie "-form_tag :action => 'form' do "

Comment: @mtay: Ah yes, you need a `do` too.

Answer (score 1):

If you must have a multi-button form then I would take a look at Ryan Bate's RailsCast on the subject:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form

Comment: thanks i saw that. didn't solve my problem. my syntax is similar.